# Who first used three stacked bars as an icon for "menu"?

Tags: icon, history

The three stacked bars for a menu (known as a “hamburger menu”) seems like a pretty new concept. Is there any canonical information out there about who created this icon?

I’m curious because it has become a pretty famous and widely used icon for “menu” in the past few years.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here are a couple of great resources that explain the origin of the hamburger menu: [Who Designed the Hamburger Icon?](http://gizmodo.com/who-designed-the-iconic-hamburger-icon-1555438787) & [A Brief History of the Hamburger Icon](http://blog.placeit.net/history-of-the-hamburger-icon/) . As the articles state, the original designer is a man named Norm Cox who designed it for the Xerox "Star" personal workstation.

[image: An image of the original from the Xerox Star]

Comment: Oh wow! It goes back to the very origin of GUI based OSes.

Comment: +1 Hamburger... Really?! Gimme a break... I have never seen it that way. I thought it was just a simple pile of stuff...

Comment: @Armfoot That name is ubiquitous.